# Program to notify when content of a UNC path is changed

Tags: windows, notification

Given a local server that is accessed by a number of users, I need to provide those users with a piece of software (on their own computers) that will notify them when files are modified in a specific folder or folders on the server.

All computers are on the same local network, and folders will be accessed by their UNC path (\\computer\folder).

It should provide a non-blocking but noticeable notification, something similar to the notifications that programs like Dropbox or Thunderbird show on file syncing/new emails.

Required:

- Notify when the content of the targeted folder(s) change
- Support UNC paths on a local network
- Provide the user with a non-blocking notification
- Runs on Windows 7+

Preferable, but not necessary:

- Can notify of changes that have occurred while the program is not running
- Option to not display notifications for deleted files
- Can determine the difference between added files and renamed files

I am happy to accept commercial software (maximum US$10 per PC) or freeware if it has all of the preferable features, but if any are missing I would prefer open source so I can attempt to add the missing features.